# Is it possible to force Sars-Cov-2 virus to mutate?

Tags: mutations, coronavirus

The title may definitely be a stupid question since I have no background in biology. I would like to know if the coronaviruses or any other can be manipulated artificially so that they stop spreading among humans and target other animals, for example cats. I like cats but they can spare one of their lives for humanity.

¿Is it possible?

Furthermore, is it possible to create a surface made of articifial cell membranes which is better than human cells for the viruses to stick? As I understand the viruses have no life, which means they are like machines, they have no aim in "life" other than stick. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you heard this suggested as a solution? How would you plan to collect all the viruses in all the different people who are infected?

Comment: I haven't heard or read anything about this. So your point is each virus is different genetically, correct?

Comment: My main point is that you'd have to introduce your mutation in every viral particle, otherwise at best what you've done is create a new virus that infects cats, while not having done anything to the 99.999999999% of virus that you haven't touched.

Comment: This idea is conceptually similar to creation of a live attenuated vaccine, where a virus is passaged through some other host (like lab animals or cultured cells). Mutations benefiting infection of the new host accumulate. Hopefully, after enough passages, it's no longer infectious to humans, but still similar enough to help an innoculated human develop immunity to the infectious form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuated_vaccine